# Azure resources incuring charges, but not visible in portal

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azureportal, azure-management

I have a VS Premium subscription to Azure.
There are resources in the subscription that are costing money, but I cannot find them when searching in the azure portal.

One is a machine learning work group.
I can see its incurring costs in the subscription section, but when i search for it to delete it, it cannot be found.

The same issue is occurring for a storage account.

Any idea how i can delete these items?

Comment: Update: I deleted a lot of old unused resources about 2 weeks ago, could the costs they incurred before deletion still be appearing in the subscription cost?

Comment: yes, if the billing period is not past then deleted resources will still be visible costs